I need to create a shortcode for an app form
I have custom app that uses a form to send data to Quickbooks to create an invoice.  A php file on C-panel contains the code for the form. The code is posted below.
    @extends('layout.mainlayout')
    @section('content')
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 mx-auto">
      <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-sm p-3">
        <!-- Credit card form content -->
        <div class="tab-content">

          <!-- credit card info-->
          <div id="nav-tab-card" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                <div class="text-center pt-5">
                  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8cDgdFX/Logo.png" alt="network-logo" width="72" height="72" />
                  
                   <h4 class="card-title mt-3 text-center">Submit Day</h4>
                </div>
                
                @if(session('success'))
                    <h6 class="alert alert-success">
                        {{ session('success') }}
                    </h6>
                @endif
                @if(session('danger'))
                    <h6 class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ session('danger') }}
                    </h6>
                @endif
            <form action="{{ url('/invoice-submit') }}" method="POST" role="form">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ofiicename">Office Name</label>
                <select name="officename" id="ofiicename" class="form-control @error('officename') is-invalid @enderror">
                    <option value="">Select Office</option>
                    <option value="Office1”>Office 1</option>
                    <option value="Office2”>Office 2</option>
                    <option value="Office3”>Office 3</option>
                    <option value="Office4”>Office 4</option>
                </select>    
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="workdate">Work Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="workdate" id="workdate" class="form-control @error('workdate') is-invalid @enderror">
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="patientComplete">Number of patients completed:</label>
                <input type="text" name="patientCompleted" id="patientComplete" placeholder="" class="form-control @error('patientCompleted') is-invalid @enderror">
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="selfpay">Number of self-pay patients completed</label>
                <input type="text" name="selfpaypatient" placeholder="" id="selfpay" class="form-control @error('selfpaypatient') is-invalid @enderror">
              </div>
        
              <button type="submit" class="subscribe btn btn-primary btn-block rounded-pill shadow-sm"> Submit  </button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- End -->

        </div>
        <!-- End -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#workdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' }).val();
</script>
@endsection`

I currently scan a QR code and it pulls up a page with the form on it.  However I want the form to be on a particular WordPress page.  How do I create a shortcode to place this form a specific Wordpress page?
I tried using the following in the theme's function.php file and in the current location of the form's php file.
function custom_function_for_your_page() {
return (form php code inserted);
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_functionality', 'custom_function_for_your_page' );


I'm unclear on what you are trying to do. A QR code (in this instance) is just a URL, so for sake of discussion let's just talk about URLs. You are also talking about shortcodes, and wanting to place forms on specific pages. Can you clarify things?

I'm sorry.  I currently use a QR code, but I don't want to.  This is why I said, "however, I want to place the form on a particular WebPress page.  I would like to place the form on the page using a shortcode.

Because you are outputting HTML directly, I think using PHP output buffering might be a good solution, see this. However, you also appear to be using a templating language beyond just PHP and HTML, so it might not work, and you might need to consult that language's documentation.
